# Dapper.Contrib and MiniProfiler (for MySql) integration issues

Tags: c#, miniprofiler, dapper-contrib

I'm trying to use MiniProfiler.Integrations.MySql along with Dapper.Contrib extensions to profile the sql queries sent to MySql server. I'm using my own ConnectionFactory:

```
public IDbConnection GetConnection()
{
    var connection = (DbConnection) new MySqlConnection(_connectionString);
    return new ProfiledDbConnection(connection, CustomDbProfiler.Current);
}
```

Dapper.Contrib allows inserting new records as simple as

```
public async Task AddAsync(TEntity sample)
{
    using (var connection = _connectionFactory.GetConnection())
    {
        await connection.InsertAsync(sample);
    }
}
```

But `ProfiledDbConnection` is interpreted as an `SQLConnection`, producing SQLServer syntax which is incompatible with MySQL:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Id], [CreatedAt], [AndSoOn]' at line 1
```

Looking for your advice on how to solve the issue and get MiniProfiler working.

I'm using (all from Nuget):

Dapper: 1.50.5
Dapper.Contrib: 1.50.5
MiniProfiler: 3.2.0
MiniProfiler.Integrations.MySql: 1.0.1

Comment: @AdemCatamak thanks for your comment, but it looks like the problem is not culture related, please read my answer below

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, in the current version you can override the type-based name resolution in Dapper.Contrib like this:

```
SqlMapperExtensions.GetDatabaseType = conn => "MySqlConnection";
```

This will override the default `connection.GetType()`-based name behavior. Still, that's not awesome, and I'll take a look if we can improve this in the next Dapper release.

Comment: btw, I've recently made a PR which adds another way for bypassing the issue, it lets to specify custom `ISqlAdapter` : [link](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/pull/1030)

Comment: @MykolaKlymyuk Will follow-up today, the reason I'm hesitant to take that route is I intend to overhaul the interface in Dapper 2 (or remove it completely)...adding it just before wouldn't be very user friendly :) (not that today is either...we just haven't had time to catch our breath on libraries until recently)

Comment: Looks this is the official answer from the author: https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/issues/953

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I've found a workaround for the `Insert()` and `InsertAsync()` methods, they accept ISqlAdapter as an optional parameter which seems to fix the issue (but still I can't use this approach for `Update()`/`UpdateAsync()`).
This is due to the fact that when you want to use `MiniProfiler` with `MySQL` and `Dapper.Contrib` you need to wrap the `MySqlConnection` which leads to `Dapper.Contrib` using the default (wrong) `ISqlAdapter`.